# Vim hides files inside directories with brackets in the name

Tags: neovim, netrw, plugin-nerdtree

I've been dealing with a huge problem of NeoVim for weeks (also applies to Vim a GVim) and I failed to find the solution on my own. What's happening is that NERDTree is hiding the content of any folder or directory that contains brackets in its name, either [] or {}. Here's an example:

[image: If I add brackets to a directory name, NERDTree just hide all the content inside that folder]

But probably, this problem is not directly related to NERDTree, maybe it's related to Netrw plugin, the default file explorer of Vim (I'm not sure, but I think that NERDTree works with Netrw on the background). See this:

[image: non description]

**Important**: Note that I first tried to open the folder "category" and it worked properly. Then, I changed the name to "[category]" and Netrw began to hide the file index.tsx inside that folder.

---

I'm on:

- CMD (Windows Terminal), recently installed.
- NeoVim, latest version.
- NERDTree, latest version.
- I updated all my plugins after having this problem, but it's still there.

I don't know what else to add. I tested the same case with a clean instalation of Vim, without configs and plugins, and I got the same behavior from the code editor. I'll be so grateful if someone here can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Welcome to this site! Just to add a bit of information: NERDTree does not rely on netrw. Since v 3.0.0 they even added a piece of code which hijacks `:e <directory>` to open NERDTree instead of netrw. If this is a bug you can consistently reproduce it's worth checking NERDTree's issue tracker and create a new one if it doesn't already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, well, please, don't push the limits for the poor Vim file managers. They are all buggy as homeless dogs. Especially when dealing with unusual file names. You can open an issue or just forget it...

Personally, I ended writing [one of my own](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-drvo). And it is pretty good at swallowing the brackets, I have to admit, but, quite probably, it has plenty of other bugs.